# PHP Allow Admins to Visit Site While Under Maintenance

Tags: php, ip

I have the following script:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($ip == ' . $ip . ') { 
  $me = false;
} elseif($me){
echo 'We are down for maintenance.';
exit;
}
```

I have tried almost everything but cannot get it to work.

The script needs to allow the `$ip` of the administrator so we can browse our website when it's down.

Please help.

Comment: You are comparing the ip with ip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare the current IP of your visitor with a specified IP of your admin user.

```
$ipOfAdmin = '127.0.0.1'; // Adjust to your real IP
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $ipOfAdmin ) { 
  echo 'We are down for maintenance.';
  exit;
}
// Here comes the rest of your script
```

Comment: but where is `$ipOfAdmin` used for?

Comment: I got it working, but you need to put the `echo 'We are down for maintenance.';` in an `else {`, thanks for your answer! :D